# PHP Exporting UTF-8 Data into Excel from Mysql

Tags: php, excel, unicode

I am using core php code to export data to excel. The following is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
//----------------------------------------
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
//----------------------------------------
$filename = "excelwork.xls";
$exists = file_exists('excelwork.xls');
if($exists)
{
    unlink($filename);
}
$filename = "excelwork.xls";
$fp = fopen($filename, "wb");
$sql = "select * from test";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$$insert = "";
$insert_rows = "";
for ($i = 1; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)
{
    $insert_rows .= mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
$insert_rows.="\n";
fwrite($fp, $insert_rows);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $insert = $row[1]. "\t" .$row[2]. "\t".$row[3]. "\t".$row[4]. "\t".$row[5];
    $insert .= "\n";               //       serialize($assoc)
    fwrite($fp, $insert);
}
if (!is_resource($fp))
{
         echo "cannot open excel file";
}
echo "success full export";
fclose($fp);
```

============ This is my Mysql Table  ================

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'सजल', 1),
(2, 'सूर्या', 1),
(3, 'धनश्री', 1),
(4, 'मनीष', 1),
(5, 'राहुल', 1);
```

The Output excel file gives this output :

```
à¤¸à¤œà¤²
à¤¸à¥‚à¤°à¥à¤¯à¤¾
à¤§à¤¨à¤¶à¥à¤°à¥€
à¤®à¤¨à¥€à¤·
à¤°à¤¾à¤¹à¥à¤²
```

But when i Export using Phpmyadmin into xls the output is correct:

```
सजल
सूर्या
धनश्री
मनीष
राहुल
```

Please tell me what is wrong on my code. I have tried many things, searched many posts.
Thanks

Comment: yes its set to utf8 --- `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,

Comment: What do you see when you open your csv in a text editor? Compare that to the csv that is exported by phpmyadmin.

Comment: @ Marcin Krawiec- both files are xls not csv. when i open both files in wordpad, i see à¤¸à¥‚à¤°à¥à¤¯à¤¾ kind of characters.

Comment: Nope, both are text files but with .xls extension. You can select encoding when you open a file in wordpad - I don't remember exactly how but I'm sure that wordpad allows to force UTF-8 encoding at opening.

Comment: Marcin - yes, when i open a new wordpad and paste a utf8 character, it looks as it should be i don't need to convert it's encoding type. But my requirement is excel file(csv or xls). I have put my 3 working days on this still no hope :(

Comment: You're not writing an Excel BIFF file, even if your file extension is .xls; you're writing a csv file with a TAB separator (note that some versions of Excel will display a warning message when opening this file) - If you want to write a real Excel BIFF (.xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) file, you'll need to use a library like [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Comment: Using PHPExcel will my problem be solved ?? any idea

Comment: If you open your csv files in wordpad using utf-8 encoding and you can only see garbage then your problem is related to the database (or connection to the db) not the csv file. If you are sure that your scripts (not phpmyadmin but your code) fetch and write correct utf-8 to the DB then you can move on and experiment with the PHPExcel or other libraries. The data that you've got in your DB was inserted using phpmyadmin or your scripts?

Comment: Data was inserted using phpmyadmin and field type is also set to utf8_bin. I have posted entire MySQL schema in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be asked several times a day at the moment

1. Use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function
2. Write a UTF-8 BOM header to the csv file before you write any other data
3. Consider using [MySQL's own export](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html)

   SELECT *
     INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     FROM test;

**EDIT**

```
$fh = fopen('test2.csv', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");       // Write UTF-8 BOM
fwrite($fh, "sep=\t" . PHP_EOL);   // Hint for MS Excel
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row, "\t");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: @ Mark - The mysql outfile din't worked. It shows à¤§à¤¨à¤¶à¥à¤°à¥€
 and not UTF-8 characters. I am trying fputcsv(). Can you please help with UTF-8 BOM header. I searched it earlier also but din't got any clue how to use it. Thanks.